# Mysql query to find any entries that contain a "non-roman" letter

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to find a query that would tell me rows that are potentially not stored in a latin script. For example:

```
location
(01811) 서울시 <-- YES
한국   <-- YES
abcdefoi18378! <-- NO
```

What would be a query for this? I'm not too familiar with the flavor of regex that mysql supports (or doesn't support) and my first stab at it was:

```
select * from ghl_map where location not regexp '\w';
```

But then from this I need to build a character class, such as `[\w,+$]`...etc. What would be the suggested way to do this?

Hopefully there's a way to do this such as `...WHERE COLLATION(language, 'asci') = language`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get the letters outside of (in your example) the [`latin1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html) character set. You could do this by comparing the current value to the latin1-encoded value. For example:

```
SELECT
    location, 
    CONVERT(location USING latin1) l2
FROM
    ghl_map
WHERE
    location !=CONVERT(location USING latin1)
```

Note: not only will this get "letters" outside the latin1 character set, it will also get things just as emojis, etc. as well:

- PH ↔️ AU
- SH❤️

So be careful in knowing what is stored in the `location` field. You could have a valid location that doesn't contain a non-latin letter but **does** contain a mark/emoji/symbol outside of that character set.